# Adonis 6 and WebSocket.io Implementation

Tags: websocket, adonis.js

I need assistance with the implementation of WebSocket.io with Adonis 6.

In the past, I successfully implemented WebSocket.io with Adonis 5 by following this [documentation](https://v5-docs.adonisjs.com/cookbooks/socketio-with-adonisjs). However, I am facing challenges in replicating the same implementation with Adonis 6.

After some investigation, I suspect that the issue may be related to the import statement:

```
import { AdonisServer } from '@adonisjs/core/app'
```

With my limited experience, I believe that this import statement might not be compatible with Adonis 6, leading to the difficulties I am encountering.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can provide to resolve this issue and successfully implement WebSocket.io with Adonis 6.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance.

Best regards,

After some investigation, I suspect that the issue may be related to the import statement:

```
import { AdonisServer } from '@adonisjs/core/app'
```

[source](https://v5-docs.adonisjs.com/cookbooks/socketio-with-adonisjs)

Comment: Hello,

I wanted to let you know that I managed to resolve the issue by following your suggestion. Thank you for your help!

Best regards,

https://twitter.com/adonisframework/status/1755867882527896019